# postgresql classpath under windows

Tags: java, postgresql, classpath

I'm running this under windows vista cmd prompt:

```
java -classpath C:\postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar -jar myJar.jar
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot load postgresql driver. org.postgresql.Driver
```

The line causing the error is:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

But in eclipse, the program works, and the postgresql library is referenced under the "Referenced Libraries".

How to fix this please ? I need to run the program under the windows cmd prompt while getting the same result I get in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: does your postgres jar file exist at that location c:\?

Comment: Do a jar -tf and confirm that it contains the org.postgresql.Driver class in it.

Comment: It doesn't contain it. So how can I fix this please ?

Comment: Find the jar file that you are using in Eclipse .. and replace this current one with that.

Comment: It is the same jar file already.

Comment: I misunderstood you. The Driver class is indeed in the postgresql library. I meant it's not in my application jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the fact that since you are using an executable jar, the classpath variable is being ignored.

You should make sure that your myJar.jar has the correct classpath entries in its manifest file using

```
Class-Path: postgres...jar
```

Make sure that its in the same directory as myJar.jar

Comment: To be precise: when using `java -jar` all other classpath definitions are ignored. That is also documented in the tools manual (see the last line for the `-jar` option): http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html